# All() is printing every time else statement

Tags: pandas

Basically pandas object is applying to entire data frame not individually
that is why it is going to `else` condition. we need to apply on each rows

I got proper output while applying on one `row` frame. While applying entire data frame I got the error `No keys` on each rows, Basically some rows of `res` have `None` only those rows are expected to be `No keys`

sample dataframe

```
res,url1,url2
{'bool': True, 'val':False},{'bool': False, 'val':False},{'bool': True, 'val':False}
None,{'bool': True, 'val':False},{'bool': False, 'val':False}
{'bool': False, 'val':False},},{'bool': True, 'val':False},{'bool': True, 'val':False}
```

Code

```
def func1():
    return ('url1')
def func2():
    return ('url2')
def test_func():
    if df['res'].str['bool'].all() and df['url1'].str['bool'].all():
        return func1()
    elif df['res'].str['bool'].all() and df['url2'].str['bool'].all():
        return func2()
    else:
        return ("No Keys")
```

Expected Out

```
output
url1
No Keys
url2
```

MY out

```
No keys
No Keys
No Kyes
```

I need to apply on the below code more than 5000 urls
`df['output'] = df.apply(test_func)`

While applying I got the error No keys on each rows

if i do `any` its passing `False` because first row of the `url1` bools is `False`

What is the issue is if all() its checking all the rows since None is present in the second rows its printing `No Keys`

Comment: can you please post the code to recreate the sample dataframe?

Comment: Your sample dataframe doesn't make any sense as a dataframe. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: All() is printing else statement? Please change title, too. Also, how func1 and func2 take an argument (row), when they are not defined to do so? Lastly, try all(df['res'].str['bool']) instead of df['res'].str['bool'].all()

Comment: @ThanasisMattas   I have tried with same out as like you, no save

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreating DataFrame

```
                             res                           url1  \
0   {'bool': True, 'val': False}  {'bool': False, 'val': False}   
1                           None   {'bool': True, 'val': False}   
2  {'bool': False, 'val': False}   {'bool': True, 'val': False}   

                            url2  
0   {'bool': True, 'val': False}  
1  {'bool': False, 'val': False}  
2   {'bool': True, 'val': False}
```

use `pd.apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x: 'url1' if (x['res'] != None and x['res'].get('bool') and x['url1'].get('bool'))\
           else 'url2' if  (x['res'] != None and x['res'].get('bool') and x['url2'].get('bool'))
           else 'No Keys',1)
```

---

```
Output

0       url2
1    No Keys
2    No Keys
dtype: object
```

**Note** - for third row, res bool value is False, so doing `and` will give false and hence `No Keys`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a nested `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

#Recreate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'res': [{'bool': True, 'val':False}, None, {'bool': False, 'val':False}],
    'url1':[{'bool': False, 'val':False}, {'bool': True, 'val':False}, {'bool': True, 'val':False}],
    'url2':[{'bool': True, 'val':False},{'bool': False, 'val':False},{'bool': True, 'val':False}]})

# Define logic
df['Output'] = np.where(df['res'].str['bool'] & df['url1'].str['bool'], 'url1',
                        np.where(df['res'].str['bool'] &  df['url2'].str['bool'], 'url2', 
                                 'No Keys'))
# Check Result
df

                  res  ...   Output
0   {'bool': True, 'val': False}  ...     url2
1                           None  ...  No Keys
2  {'bool': False, 'val': False}  ...  No Keys
```